# partial responses from remote server

Tags: html, http

I'm posting this question here, but I'm not 100% sure where the problem lies. I have a site hosted through Media Temple that I'm developing. It's started to continually give me http 206 responses (partial content) on image and js assets. I see these through firebug. This results in missing images and js files, or in some browsers like Safari, half rendered images. When I view my work off my local server I see no issues.

I see this behavior on all browsers, firefox 3.6, safari 5.0.3, chrome 8. I work off of mac os x 10.6.6. Different images exhibit this behavior at different times, and the only thing that works temporarily is to clear the cache, but I'll typically begin to see the problem again shortly.

The other thing, as much as I can tell, I don't see this problem on other machines. My work machine (also a Mac) doesn't show this behavior at all. The clients this site is for have never complained of these issues at all.

I've also taken some of these problematic assets and moved them to other servers and pointed my browser there, no problem, so it doesn't seem to be a corrupt file.

I've run out of places to look and was hoping someone on these forums might have some suggestions. This is a real mystery and would love to get to the bottom of it.

Comment: Hi, you want to try serverfault.com. That's the place full of sysadmins.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a problem on the server side. Have you tried restarting the web server or taking a look at the error log?